# Apache Nifi - OpenID Connect - Unable to validate token

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid, apache-nifi

I am using OpenID connect authorization provider with Apache Nifi. The authorization is provided by Azure Active Directory.

The implicit grant flow is working fine and I am able to login to the Nifi UI.

However, when I am generating a toke using client credentials flow through Azure AD and using it in Nifi. I am getting the following error :-

```
Unable to validate the access token.
```

Upon inquiring further in the Nifi logs. The complete error log is this :-

```
2020-03-23 11:33:07,408 ERROR [NiFi Web Server-30] o.a.nifi.web.security.jwt.JwtService Unable to validate the access token.
Caused by: The default resolveSigningKey(JwsHeader, Claims) implementation cannot be used for asymmetric key algorithms (RSA, Elliptic Curve).  Override the resolveSigningKey(JwsHeader, Claims) method instead and return a Key instance appropriate for the RS256 algorithm.
2020-03-23 11:33:07,408 WARN [NiFi Web Server-30] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Rejecting access to web api: Unable to validate the access token.
```

From what I understand, RS256 signed tokens are not supported by Apache Nifi or am I doing something wrong ?

Here is the token that is working after implicit flow.

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1ZjVlOTc0Zi04YzcxLTQ2NTctYTk1My1hODNhMjMzNGFkZTciLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvZ2luLm1pY3Jvc29mdG9ubGluZS5jb20vNWY1ZTk3NGYtOGM3MS00NjU3LWE5NTMtYTgzYTIzMzRhZGU3L3YyLjAiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2xvZ2luLm1pY3Jvc29mdG9ubGluZS5jb20vNWY1ZTk3NGYtOGM3MS00NjU3LWE5NTMtYTgzYTIzMzRhZGU3L3YyLjAiLCJwcmVmZXJyZWRfdXNlcm5hbWUiOiI1ZjVlOTc0Zi04YzcxLTQ2NTctYTk1My1hODNhMjMzNGFkZTciLCJraWQiOjIsImV4cCI6MTU4NDk5MDM1MywiaWF0IjoxNTg0OTg2NzU0fQ.j-n7HbniajEItWUMNWwoD9Ds17focVPD1Bng23KCCF8
```

Here is the token generated using client credentials flow that is not working :-

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IllNRUxIVDBndmIwbXhvU0RvWWZvbWpxZmpZVSIsImtpZCI6IllNRUxIVDBndmIwbXhvU0RvWWZvbWpxZmpZVSJ9.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.GOVOxmNPT3p8aa8pRlcssfq-R4beflrG343BQM-MAtqHEIwAyHfDX0K3BmV5-SVSnNlt8BKBXicq-IgtiHtdo4HLWAEu7FGH2udH-SJwMbk4_kmH8RaE-zps_ZUjt_L04dZpwK5e-VfRmBkIFKh-KkxvXVabyvLfgJZCwPq4_d_mP0PK4Jmx0xibysYMIbyw0Le883-2GCXVACLZfxQAwblaZiS1LXe7cBkyp508Ij_GZCs4sTwZ7_p6uydx0MqdFUtQVyJOO5pCRo0fDLmKWfAme8uqz36gOa9g6chpALCQfbSBMsZbZxPT9eRSFCZaezuayuh03wFipO_tvzAyEA
```

And this is the openid discovery url :-

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/5f5e974f-8c71-4657-a953-a83a2334ade7/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Comment: any luck here? I am also facing same issue

Comment: Are you running NiFi as a standalone, or as a cluster?